# Calling Jabber sdk for web through firefox add-on

Tags: jquery, firefox-addon, voip, cisco, message-passing

Here is the scenario....

**Scenario**:
   I have developed a Mozilla add-on which detects the phone numbers on a given web page and highlights the number with a hyperlink. Now comes the real question....

When the user clicks on the number, the click event should call the Jabber SDK plugin to initiate the audio/video communication.

**Problem**:
   I am unable to figure out how the add-on can call the plugin. Is Message Passing a solution? If it is , I need some guidance to figure it out.

Hope my question is clear to everyone.